# if I disconect a harddrive wil it be erased ?

Tags: hard-drive

got a McBookPro (2009) At this moment it is locked with ("#0* gdmd) FILE VAULT application that refuses my password. I"m seeking a way to disable filevault.
I tried to re install the software but I can't access. So, my question is : If I succeed to disconnect the harddrive, will it erased ? If yes, I don't worry about the datas inside, but I need my pc working a new though I'll have to reset my own parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No, just disconnecting the hard drive will not erase the contents of the drive.

Of course, if the drive is fully encrypted, the contents won't be accessible to anyone. But they'll still be there.

Comment: Ok, do you think there is an alternative meanning to reset the pc before planning to change the harddrive ?

Comment: I don'i understand this.

Comment: @MATEO, you didn't say "reset the pc", you asked about disconnecting the hard drive. Simply unplugging the hard drive will not erase it. Curious, why don't you just format the drive?